# Why is this set not in the sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A_n = \sigma \{I_k = [k-1, k) | k = 1,... , n\}$ Show that $\cup^{\infty}_{1} A_n$ is not a sigma-algebra in R.

My thought is that $\cup^{\infty}_{k=1}I_k$ will be an example of how $\cup^{\infty}_{1} A_n$ won't be closed under countable union. How can I prove that $\cup^{\infty}_{k=1}I_k$ does not belong to $\cup^{\infty}_{1} A_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We can write down all sets in $A_n$: they are just all possible unions of the sets $[0,1), [1,2),...,[n-1,n), [n, \infty), (-\infty, 0)$. [To prove this verify that these unions form  sigma algebra and that this sigma algebra is the smallest one containing $[0,1), [1,2),...,[n-1,n)$]. Now you can easily see that $\bigcup [2n,2n+1)$ does not belong to $\cup A_n$ though each $[2n,2n+2) $ belongs to $\bigcup A_n$.

Comment: I am kind of confused. I don't see how they are all possible unions of the sets that you have listed. I think what you are doing is to use the fact that each An is finite to arrive at the contradiction, but I don't exact follow your hint. For instance, R is in all $A_n$, but the largest union that can be formed is $[0, \infty)$. In addition, I think you meant each [2n, 2n+1) at the very end.

Comment: @WilliamAmbrose Sorry. I was working in $[0,\infty)$. All you have to do is to include $(-\infty,0)$ to that collection.